# Object value can not be changed

Tags: c++, oop, variables, object, scope

I am a new c++ programmer, and have learned some java before. I am do my assignment. And I just could not get my heard around this problem.

```
class A{
private:
 bool test;

public:
 void anotherSetTest();
     void setTest();
 A();
};
 void Globle_scope_function(A a){
  a.setTest(true);
}

A::A(){
  test = false;
}
void A::setTest(bool foo){
      test = foo;
}
void A::anotherSetTest(){
   Globle_scope_function(*this);
}
int main(){
  A a;
  a.anotherSetTest();
  cout<<a.getTest()<<endl;//It suppose to output true, but why does it output false. 
      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

When I use visual studio to debug, it tells me that the object has gone out of scope. How do I solve it...  :-< . Edit it to MWV.

Comment: If you want to modify the value from the call site you need to pass by reference.

Comment: @Peter Chen  Show minimal verifiable example.

Comment: **Unlike** in Java, in C++ object names are NOT references under the hood. You are passing a copy of object to `Globle_scoop_function(A a)` (and probably to `setTest`). You need to learn about [C++ references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) and use them

Comment: "I am a new c++ programmer, and have learned some java before." You have many things to unlearn. C++ isn't Java, and that's a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Globle_scoop_function(*this);` takes a *deep copy* of `*this` to the function parameter `a`. It's *that* object that goes out of scope at the end of `Globle_scoop_function`. The object `*this` remains unmodified.

One remedy would be to change the prototype to `void Globle_scoop_function(A& a){`. Note the `&` which denotes a *reference*. You then modify the `a` in `main()` *through* that reference.

The fact that all the various instances of `A` in your code are all called `a` only adds to the confusion.

Comment: Why did you decide that the VC++ bothers about this?